# How to monitor data from data from serial FTDI chip on Ubuntu

Tags: serial-port, usbserial, ftdi

I have a device with an FTDI serial to USB convertor. I want to monitor/datalog the data coming from this device.
On Windows using a serial monitor, all is Ok I can see the frames coming.

Now I want to do that on Ubuntu. :

The chip device seems to be detected : "`dmesg | grep FTDI`" :

```
[ 2449.998852] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 2450.018939] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[ 2450.018999] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 2450.019382] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Then I tried gtkterm with all the same serial parameters from windows : baudrate, parity, data bits, stop bits, RTS/CTS : no data, no error message, same thing with minicom.

I also tried with pyserial on Python but I'm not confident with that and the result : no data.

In advance thanks for answers !!

Comment: did u already try it with super user right? Because I recall that one has either to use elevated rights or set the access rules correctly.

Comment: Yes I've done it with sudo